# How to create and use multiple "dancer cards" in Just Dance 2015 on Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one, just-dance-2015

I have had previous Just Dance games (2013, 2014) on the Wii, and just got an Xbox One with Kinect and purchased Just Dance 2015.
On the older games -- at least on the Wii -- I was able to create 3 different "Dancer Cards" (one for myself, one for my wife, one for my child), which tracked progress separately and allowed us to play together.

In Just Dance 2015 (at least on Xbox One), it is limiting me to a single Dancer Card at a time. If I am logged in, it shows my Dancer Card, which is associated with my Live Account. If my wife is logged in (and not me), it shows hers (associated with her separate Live Account). And when I am logged in, I can see her in my list of "friends' Dancer Cards", but can't find a way to "select" it.
And if we want to play together, we have to choose one account as the "primary Dancer Card", and all stats/achievements are mashed together into that single account.

Furthermore, when I start a dance, it only allows us to choose from fixed names (Crazy, Funky, Happy, Sunny, etc), rather than allowing our dancers to have "our" names.

Is there any way to allow multiple Dancer Cards to play together on local multiplayer, and/or to allow personalized names (i.e. "Josh" instead of "Crazy") to show up during a dance?

I guess as a secondary question: Is this only a limitation in the Xbox One version, or is it pretty much the same on other platforms?

Comment: "all stats/achievements are mashed together into that single account" - do you mean with the addition that each player earns achievements/stats to their account at the same time, as well?

Comment: What i mean is that the game does not "see" other accounts currently logged in simultaneously. It only records achievements and stats for the "primarily-logged-in" profile. I only have Lego Batman 3 to compare this to, and in Lego Batman, it attaches one user profile to each player and records their achievements separately.